# Tensorflow 2.2.0 InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [98,2] vs. [32,2]

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I was trying to build a gender classification model (2 classes) using data augmentation.

My data consists of 2 folders named 'men' and 'women' having total of 3339 images.
datapath = 'data/'
inside data folder i have the two class folders named men and women.

Here is my model and model summary:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal', input_shape=(128,128,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(units=256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
                 epochs=30,
                 steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0]//32,
                 validation_data=(x_test,y_test),
                 validation_steps=x_test.shape[0]//32,
                 verbose=1,
                 callbacks=callbacks)
```

model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 32)      2432      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_16 (Activation)   (None, 128, 128, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 32)      25632     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_17 (Activation)   (None, 128, 128, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPooling2 (None, 64, 64, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)          (None, 64, 64, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_19 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 64)        51264     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_18 (Activation)   (None, 64, 64, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_20 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 64)        102464    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_19 (Activation)   (None, 64, 64, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_9 (MaxPooling2 (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_9 (Dropout)          (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_4 (Flatten)          (None, 65536)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 256)               16777472  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 514       
=================================================================
Total params: 16,959,778
Trainable params: 16,959,778
Non-trainable params: 0
```

My training and testing data shapes:

```
x_train.shape = (3005, 224, 224, 3)
x_test.shape = (334, 224, 224, 3)
y_train.shape = (3005, 2)
y_test.shape = (334, 2)
```

Following error:

```
Epoch 1/30

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-42-f9e107b66258> in <module>()
     13                  validation_steps=x_test.shape[0]//32,
     14                  verbose=1,
---> 15                  callbacks=callbacks)

8 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [98,2] vs. [32,2]
     [[node gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at <ipython-input-42-f9e107b66258>:15) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5749]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape of each of your images seems to be (224,224,3) and you specified (128,128,3) as input_shape. Could that be the problem?
If not, could you please share the code where you define x_train and x_test?
Also, note that defining a two-dimensional output with a sigmoid activation for a binary classifier doesn't seem right. I would either have a single unit with a sigmoid activation (the most common scenario) or use a softmax activation.

```
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

or

```
model.add(Dense(units=num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: i don't know how i didn't notice the shape, actually i changed the training shapes but i forgot to change the shape in the model, my bad.
And also yes, using softmax would be more logical here, i thought we use sigmoid for binary classes (2).

Comment: Sure, for binary classes you can use sigmoid if you specify a single unit. In that case, the model outputs the probability of one of the classes, being 1 - the output the probability of the training instance belonging to the other one. If you use a softmax activation with two units, then both outputs would be normalised to add up to one, and one neuron would output 1 - the other. This approach adds parameters to your model and it doesn't really make a difference, so I'd recommend against it. Glad you solved your issue!

Comment: cool, also instead of binary crossentropy, using categorical crossentropy would be more logical right?

Comment: Good point. Indeed, if you output more than one unit you should probably use a categorical cross-entropy loss for a problem like this one.